# How to fix 'gtm' is undefined error in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-tag-manager

I'm using google tag manager to paste some general purpose scripts in my project, and I need it to be able to run IE9.

But when I attempt to execute the script in browser I get the following error:

> SCRIPT5009: 'gtm' is undefined

This is a little breakdown of the script (redacted sensitive data).

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){
    w[l]=w[l]||[];
    w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
    var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    var j=d.createElement(s);
    var dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
    j.async=true;
    j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxxxx');
```

I understand that IE9 doesn't support this:

```
w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
```

However, I wonder if there's a workaround for this issue. I've been searching for an answer but I found nothing helpful.

Comment: You can try to refer this link may give you some information that may help to understand the issue in better way. Ref: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/undefined-variable-in-google-tag-manager/#gref I can see that you are using IE 9. IE 9 is outdated and currently not supported. It is recommended to upgrade to IE 11.

Comment: Deepak-MSFT using ie 9 is part of customer requirements, some of their systems depend directly on using internet explorer and not meeting this requirement might cause them to stop using our app.

Comment: I try to search for a possible solution or a work around. at present, I did not found any work around that can help to avoid the issue. I will try to inform you if I get any relevant information in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: What makes you think that IE9 does not support a simple Array.push? That has been supported since 5.5... there is nothing in the code that you posted that would trigger that error, and as others have pointed out, you should look to see what else is calling GTM. If you look at the console error for `SCRIPT5009`, it might show a filename below it and line of code that triggered the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you redacted from that block, but whatever that is, seems to be throwing that error. 'gtm' is undefined to me seems like you calling a variable set as 'gtm' in the script. The block you posted only has 'gtm' referenced in a string.

Comment: This is the only place in my entire app in which ".gtm" or anything alike is found.